# NFS Migration automation (CentOS 5)

Tags: bash, nfs, ansible, centos5

I need a little help with an upcoming migration. The storage team has implemented a new netapp stack. Once I have a tested script, I have around 400 servers across two environments that I'll need to migrate.

Each server has a current nfs mount pointed to the old storage stack. All these current mounts have different names.

ex: `/mnt/existing_mount`

I need to mount a new NFS share, rsync the contents, and leave the share with the same original name.

Here's the process I was thinking:

1. Stop writes on `/mnt/existing_mount` (This can be done through the netapp admin by disabling writes)
2. pull `/mnt/existing_mount` name into variable
3. mount the new nfs volume to `/mnt/new_mount`
4. rsync all files to `/mnt/new_mount` (preserving local permissions)
5. unmount `/mnt/existing_mount`
6. rename `/mnt/new_mount` based on variable

Am I approaching this efficiently? Does anyone know of an ansible playbook or script that will already do this?

Answer (score 2):

We recently had to do something like this with our NFS share on our Netapp. We're retiring our Netapp and moving to Nimble Storage. Your process is very similar to what we did with a few exceptions. This is the high level process we used.

1. Mount new NFS to server using temporary path in fstab file
2. Use rsync to make an initial copy of existing files from old NFS to new NFS
3. Update fstab file and change mount point so old NFS points to temp
   location and new NFS points to the same name as the what the old NFS
   used to use
4. Prevent writes to the old NFS
5. Use rsync to make a final copy of any files from old NFS
   to new NFS to catch anything that changed while the first copy was
   taking place

We were using this to migrate a mailstore for customer email. This process allowed us to move the mails while the system was live with only a small 5 minute service interruption when we remounted the NFS shares after changing their mount point names and re-syncing the last of the changes.